# Intel RST turned a disk off

Tags: hard-drive, raid, sata, intel-rst, asus-laptop

I have an Asus ROG laptop and I got a BSOD while I was working and then after the restart, one of my partitions disappeared.

[image: wtf]

This used to show two disks but it only shows 1 disk and the cd drive. Any ideas?

[image: huh]